# MongoRepository findOne using "id" instead of "_id"

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a setup very similar to this one: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

In my POJO class I use a String field (annotated with @Id) and set it manually.

```
public class MyPojo {
  @Id
  private String id

  public MyPojo(String id) {
    this.id = id
  }

  //...
}
```

Like in the example I use an extended interface of MongoRepository:

```
public interface MyPojoRepository extends MongoRepository<MyPojo, String> {

}
```

When I save my object

```
myrepo.save(new MyPojo("user"));
```

Everything works fine and in my collection _id = "user" as I expect it to be.

However, if I want to query that object now:

```
myrepo.findOne("user")
```

I receive null. The debug log shows that my collection is queried with

> { "id" : "user" }

instead of "_id". Is this behavior intended? I find this very confusing. Especially because the JavaDoc explicitly mentions the term "id" here.

//EDIT:

```
myrepo.exists("user")
```

returns true...

Comment: I tried to give you an answer. Let me know if that's clear or you need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to change the field name saved in the MongoDB is by using the following annotation:
[import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/package-summary.html)

by using the annotation you can define the field name in the mongoDB.

For example:

```
@Field("email")
private EmailAddress emailAddress;
```

Now **emailAddress** will be saved in the database using the key **email**.

The mongoDB will always use the **_id** as one of the document's unique identifier.

In the case you have you can make another field calls **userId**, which can be duplication of the **_id** field but with the syntax you like, such as:

```
@Field("id")
private String userId;
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the constructor

```
 public MyPojo(String id) {
   this.id = id
 }
```

because you must not assign the *id* manually.

MongoDB uses this field internally and you are about to put a string into an ObjectID field type.

Simply provide an empty constructor and/or constructor that initialize fields that are part of the document (that is field of type String for *user*.

In the link of your guide you have a good example!